# Вытащить часть из строки: найти от одной до трёх цифр внутри скобок []

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть строка такого вида:

`AAA 356 125 [654:11233:1123] 255 255 255 [123]: abc`

Нужно вытащить из этой строки эту часть: `123`, которая находится в `[123]:`.

`123` может быть любым другим числом (но только числом), как минимум однозначным и как максимум трехзначным (`5`, `999`, `0`, `88`, etc).

Не могу разобраться в регулярных выражениях, постоянно выходит что-то не так.

```
line = 'AAA 356 125 [654:11233:1123] 255 255 255 [123]: abc'
search = re.search('[(\d??)]:', line)
# Пытался найти от 1 до 3 цифр между [ и ]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 123 может быть любым другим числом (но только числом), как минимум однозначным и как максимум трехзначным (5, 999, 0, 88, etc).

```
>>> re.search(r'\[(\d{1,3})\]', line).group(1)
'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вначале заэкранировать  символ "**[**" , это делается вот так **\[**
потом ищешь любое число или символ **\w**
если только число, то **\d**
и добавляешь сколько их может быть **+**(плюсом) до символа **\]** и символа **:**
а там что хочешь то и делаешь.
**'\[\w+\]:'** - регулярное выражение
**'\[\d+\]:'** - регулярное выражение если только цифры

```
import re
line = 'AAA 356 125 [654:11233:1123] 255 255 255 [123]: abc'
search = re.search('\[\w+\]:', line)
s = search.group()[1:-2]
print(s)
```